# Как в форме поиска передать параметр в action

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

У меня есть форма поиска

```
<li style="list-style-type: none;" class="search">
    <form id="search" method="post" action="Home/index">
        <div class="wrpapperInSearchForm">
            <div>
                <label asp-for="SearchText"></label>
                <input asp-for="SearchText" />
                <span asp-validation-for="SearchText"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="inputSearch"><input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" /></div>
            <div class="buttonSearch"><button type="submit">Search</button></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</li>
```

Но в качестве модели у меня не ArticleItem - (модель для статей на сайте), PaginatedList<NewsApp.Domain.Entities.ArticleItem> - потому что у меня на сайте есть пагинация.

Не могу разобраться, как мне сделать чтобы я вводил в input текст, нажимал кнопку search и этот текст передавался параметром в post method Index. У меня в модели ArticleItem, есть для этого свойство SearchText, т к модель во view у меня не ArticleItem, то я не могу использовать свойство SearchText для сохранения введенного текст, как и куда мне можно схоранить введенный текст? с ViewBag тоже не получается или я не так делаю..

вот форма поиска с моделью

```
@model PaginatedList<NewsApp.Domain.Entities.ArticleItem>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<!-- Main -->
<div id="main">

    <li style="list-style-type: none;" class="search">
        <form id="search" method="post" action="Home/index">
            <div class="wrpapperInSearchForm">
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="SearchText"></label>
                    <input asp-for="SearchText" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="SearchText"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="inputSearch"><input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" /></div>
                <div class="buttonSearch"><button type="submit">Search</button></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </li>
```

Comment: Но ведь в [туториале](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-5.0) именно это и делается: передаётся строка поиска в метод `Index`. А используется пагинация или нет - не важно

Comment: спасибо, виноват, всм туповат, или чёт запарился, по идеи просто все, согласен)

Comment: У вас должно быть две (как минимум) кнопки: `Search` (Поиск) и `Next` (Далее). При нажатии на Поиск должны передаваться на сервер новые введённые значения для фильтрации и 0 как индекс страницы. При нажатии на Далее должны передаваться на сервер прежние значения поиска и следующий индекс страницы.

Comment: эмм, да я разобрался уже, но по моему ответу не понятно было этого конечно, по туториолу всё разобрал, спасибо за ответы))